# Installing a windows 10 OS on a previously used SSD; Do I have to format the previously used SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

So previously I did a cloning job from an old HDD to a new SSD. Simply put, I botched it by immediately booting using the SSD without removing the old HDD (first rule of cloning: don't do that).

So I'm stuck with two drives with broken bootloaders. Since I'm in a hurry and the files don't really matter to me, I am opting to install a new OS instead on the SSD.

I am worried about the cloning procedure having already made partitions and such on the SSD; Can I simply use a USB bootable drive, then install the OS on the said SSD without formatting it back to its clean state, or do I have to reformat the SSD before installing an OS to it? I only have 1 computer so reformatting the SSD is a hard task given that my only computer has no bootable OSs to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation disk will reformat the disk for you - as part of the installation process, by default on almost every mainstream OS. If you're doing something hipster like haiku, or a more 'basic' install like gentoo does you might need to, but with Windows 10, or more mainstream linux based OSes, you should be fine.

Comment: solid, I went through the process and it did format by itself